# Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function?

Tags: pine-script

I have experiencing problem to include a mutable variable as an argument for security function. I tried wrapping the code with a mutable variable in a function, like this article suggested. But it doesn't seem to work for me on v4. The security function is required because my strategy runs on 4 different timeframes. The following code is a simplified version to show where the issue occurs. Any advices?
https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Pine_Version_3_Migration_Guide#Resolving_a_problem_with_a_mutable_variable_in_the_security_expression

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="My Strategy", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close=true)


// —————————— STATE

hasOpenTrade = strategy.opentrades != 0


// —————————— VARIABLES

var maxSinceLastBuySell = 0.
var minSinceLastBuySell = 0.


// —————————— FUNCTIONS

if hasOpenTrade
    maxSinceLastBuySell := max(maxSinceLastBuySell, high)
    minSinceLastBuySell := min(minSinceLastBuySell, low)


// —————————— MAIN

price_B = low < maxSinceLastBuySell * 0.9 ? 1 : 0
price_B_persistence = sum(price_B, 2) == 2 ? true : false

price_S() => 
    sum((high > minSinceLastBuySell * 1.1 ? 1 : 0), 2) == 2


// —————————— EXECUTIONS

longCondition = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", price_B_persistence)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition_sec = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", price_S())
if (shortCondition_sec)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put there different security and then choose one of the depending on your needs:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
s = bar_index % 2 == 0 ? security("F", "1", close) : security("BA", "1", close)
plot(s)
```

In your case it'll be something like:

```
...
// one security when the price_B_persistence is true and one - when it false
longCondition = price_B_persistence ? security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", true) : security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", false)
...
shortCondition_sec = price_S() ? security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", true) : security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", false)
```

```
price_S(h) => 
    sum((h > minSinceLastBuySell * 1.1 ? 1 : 0), 2) == 2

high60 = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", high)
shortCondition_sec = price_S(high60)
```

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: With the solution I offer, you should create a security per an option, so you don't need to use a mutable variable with the security. I've update my answer to show how it should look in your code. But bear in mind, that there's only 40 securities allowed per a script.

Comment: if `price_S()` is `true`, then `shortCondition_sec` gets `security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", true)`  value, else, if `price_S()` is `false`, then `shortCondition_sec gets` `security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", false)` The ternary operator is described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F: Moreover, I don't know what's your goal. Maybe it'd be better to use `high60 = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", high)` and then use the value in the `price_S()` Check out my last change in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated explanation. I do like the new approach of storing candle value from different timeframe into specific variables a lot, and I have been trying it. A new problem arises though, is that let's say the “15” timeframe inside security will not be able to run every “15” mins (no matter lookahead is on/off), since most of the logics inside my strategy need to run primarily on “60” timeframe and on the 1Hr viewport in order to get the correct value. What would be the best approach to get around it? Feels like this is the last piece of the puzzle.

Comment: You can't get all the 15 mins on the 60 timeframe. Actually, requsting lower resolution is rather useless, because each bar of the main timframe is able to have exact only one value of a reqiered timeframe. So if you are requiring higher timframe (e.g. daily bar), then its value will be copied to bars of lower resolution (of the same day). If you are requiring lower timeframe (e.g. 1 min) - only one bar (the first or the last one) of the lower timeframe will be taken for the main timeframe.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michel!