# Tradingview pine script is a piece of poop: Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function

Tags: syntax, pine-script, technical-indicator

Honestly how hard is it to implement options without a backend problem in a scripting language. I get the following error "Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function" just because I keep passing in a variable that was set in an if statement. Tried variable indirection, function indirection, in all manner of permutations, even some I know have been successful with this but issue still persists.

I want a clean way to code this without having to use ternary operations or function work around. Ternary operations and function work around are suggested in the duplicate question but does not answer what I am looking for. Any programming language scripting or object oriented have the ability to use if statements to handle options, this language does not.

```
// @version=4
study("multi_ma_pos", "multi_ma", overlay=true)

get_period(interval_input) =>
    period = ""
    if (timeframe.isintraday)
        interval = interval_input > timeframe.multiplier ? interval_input : timeframe.multiplier
        period := tostring(interval)
    else
        period := timeframe.period
    period

ma_opt = input(title="ma_opt", defval="13/34", options=["23/75/616", "13/34"])
ma_interval = input(title="ma_interval", type=input.integer, defval=240)

// Declare variables
shrt_term = close
midt_term = close
long_term = close
is_opt_selected = false

if (ma_opt == "23/75/616" and not is_opt_selected)
    shrt_term := sma(close, 23)
    midt_term := sma(close, 65)
    long_term := sma(close, 137)
    is_opt_selected := true

if (ma_opt == "13/34" and not is_opt_selected)
    shrt_term := ema(close, 13)
    midt_term := ema(close, 34)
    long_term := sma(close, 34)      
    is_opt_selected := true

shrt_term_out = security(syminfo.tickerid, get_period(ma_interval), shrt_term)
midt_term_out = security(syminfo.tickerid, get_period(ma_interval), midt_term)
long_term_out = security(syminfo.tickerid, get_period(ma_interval), long_term)

plot(shrt_term_out, title="shrt_term", color=#ffa726, linewidth=2)
plot(midt_term_out, title="midt_term", color=#ffa726, linewidth=4)
plot(long_term_out, title="long_term", color=#e65100, linewidth=4)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59448441/cannot-use-a-mutable-variable-as-an-argument-of-the-security-function)

Comment: Not really. Its the solution I was trying to avoid, the code looks messier with such inline conditionals and doesn't scale if I add more than two options. Honestly, this post was more to promote awareness that tradingview pinescript is lacking as a language and the developers of the language need to feel pressure from the community that these limitations are ridiculous. https://devrant.com/rants/1982830/pinescript-is-absolute-garbage-its-tradingviews-scripting-language-it-works-but

Comment: Prohibition of mutable variables in a security has some fundamental roots. Were it allowed, a user could get up to 8 bytes * 10000 bars * 10000 different values = 800 MB of RAM. And considering that a script can have 40 securities, a user could request 32 GB of RAM. I suppose it's oblivious that no one would allowed that, so there's the restriction. I looked at the link you've provided and that's rubbish. Most of the problems is that people take a simple tool which intended to be only used to connection together several indicators and draw a result, and use the tool to calculate moon landing.

Comment: such restrictions can still be respected. I don't see your point, as pine script compiler has no problem throwing an error regarding the memory resource constraint. I can't use if statements and I can't pass in an ema() function with different lengths because it causes an issue in this script. I have another script where I can pass in a mutable length to ema to the security function and I believe its version 3 vs version 4 centered issue. Its not that people trying to calculate a moon landing, its more like people can't display 2+2 without using a plot command.

Comment: its funny you bring up the moon landing as it already been solved, almost over 50 years ago and at that time it was pioneering. These language issues have also been solved 10 years ago. Going backwards is not a sensible argument.

Comment: Here is another rubbish thing - when you try to do a text compare between two strings, pine script is unable to test characters like "&".

Comment: Yes, I'm glad that you've got my point - those problems were solved in relevant tools and even though 50 years ago fortran had matrix multiplication out of the box, it doesn't mean that every calculator must have it too - it's just silly. I didn't understand your issue with the char '&' - just checked and it works perfectly.

Comment: really? When one of my options in my example code had an '&' pine script clearly ran over it and didn't test true. Changing it to 'n' worked. In reference to your other comment, I'm just gonna agree to disagree - clearly its an impasse. I'm in no way accepting your point, I'm actually arguing against the note that I can't run certain pieces of code within if statements and for loops. I'm asking TV support to adjust my code, let's see what their team says. I'm sure it will be along the lines...oh there is a bug but here is a workaround the bug..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer based on the suggestion from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59448441/cannot-use-a-mutable-variable-as-an-argument-of-the-security-function). Its far from ideal but perhaps for someone out there who has this issue, they can benefit from going full circle from a problem, a suggestion and then to a solution to this incompetent issue. Hopefully the following solution has a coding style some consider easy to read.

```
// @version=4
study("multi_ma_pos", "multi_ma", overlay=true)

get_period(interval_input) =>
    period = ""
    if (timeframe.isintraday)
        interval = interval_input > timeframe.multiplier ? interval_input : timeframe.multiplier
        period := tostring(interval)
    else
        period := timeframe.period
    period

ma_opt = input(title="ma_opt", defval="13/34", options=["23/75/616", "13/34"])
ma_interval = input(title="ma_interval", type=input.integer, defval=240)

get_multi_ma(ma_opt, ma_interval) =>
    // delcare output variables
    shrt_term_out = float(na)
    midt_term_out = float(na)
    long_term_out = float(na)

    period = get_period(ma_interval)

    shrt_term_out := (ma_opt == "23/75/616")  ? security(syminfo.tickerid, period, ema(close, 23)) 
       : security(syminfo.tickerid, period, sma(close, 13))

    midt_term_out := (ma_opt == "23/75/616")  ? security(syminfo.tickerid, period, ema(close, 75)) 
       : security(syminfo.tickerid, period, sma(close, 34))

    long_term_out := (ma_opt == "23/75/616")  ? security(syminfo.tickerid, period, ema(close, 616)) : security(syminfo.tickerid, period, ema(close, 34))

    // out the output variables
    [shrt_term_out, midt_term_out, long_term_out]

[shrt_term_out, midt_term_out, long_term_out] = get_multi_ma(ma_opt, ma_interval)

plot(shrt_term_out, title="shrt_term", color=#ffa726, linewidth=2)
plot(midt_term_out, title="midt_term", color=#ffa726, linewidth=4)
plot(long_term_out, title="long_term", color=#e65100, linewidth=4)
```

Comment: why tradingview does not support python as builtin script?

Comment: idk they just want to be difficult...